# Unity Mobile: How can we safely store our API key?

Tags: unity, android, ios, mobile, security

We're making an app in Unity. We're building it for Android and iOS.
We also have a server. In order to use our server you need to present our api key for the server.

So, we need to store that key in the build somewhere (eg. APK file)

But how can we put it anywhere where people wont be able to get it?
Eg. they can get the APK and decompile it.

SDKS for unity for facebook and so on, store an api key in the client. What do they do?

Comment: The framework is different, but I believe everything covered in this other question applies to your situation as well: [I want to use the GameJolt API, how do I protect my private key which is in my game?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/139469/i-want-to-use-the-gamejolt-api-how-do-i-protect-my-private-key-which-is-in-my-g)

Comment: For Unity, than writing your own encryption algorithms, you can use the encryption features built into .Net: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/security/encrypting-data . Be aware that **any use of encryption may place export limitations on your app**.